# MP4 video file uploaded to Azure Blob storage is not played

Tags: c#, azure, video-streaming, azure-blob-storage, azure-sdk

I am using the below code to upload an MP4 video file to azure blob storage. The file uploads successfully but when I hit the URL of the file in the browser it never plays. However, If I upload the same file to blob storage from the Azure portal, it plays. Not sure what could be wrong with my c# code.

```
public async Task<string> UploadVideoFileAsync(IFormFile file, string fileName, string containerName, IDictionary<string, string>? metadata = null)
{
    var containerClient = _blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
    try
    {
        await containerClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
        var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName);
        using (Stream stream = file.OpenReadStream())
        {
            stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);                
            await blobClient.UploadAsync(stream, new BlobUploadOptions
            {
                HttpHeaders = new BlobHttpHeaders { ContentType = "video/mp4" }
            });
        }

        if (metadata != null)
        {
            await blobClient.SetMetadataAsync(metadata);
        }

        return blobClient.Uri.ToString();
    }
    catch (RequestFailedException ex)
    {
        // Handle the exception here, e.g., log or return an error message.
        return $"Error uploading the file: {ex.Message}";
    }
}
```

File uploaded with the above code not played in browser:
[image]

Comment: Hi, @Reza Shirazi Is the video not working with the blob URL or localhost?

Comment: What is the size of the blob uploaded by the code? Is it the same as the source file on your local computer?

Comment: The issue was the size of the file- I was passing the wrong file object. It is fixed now. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> MP4 video file uploaded to Azure Blob storage is not played

You can use the below code to upload the video mp4 file using C#.

**Code:**

```
namespace BlobStorageDemo
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string connectionString = "xxxx";
            string containerName = "test";
            string fileName = "sample7.mp4";
            string filePath = "<path of file>";
            string contentType = "video/mp4";

            BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
            BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
            BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(fileName);

            FileStream fileStream = null;
            try
            {
                fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);
                blobClient.Upload(fileStream, new BlobUploadOptions
                {
                    HttpHeaders = new BlobHttpHeaders { ContentType = contentType }
                });
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error uploading the file: {ex.Message}");
            }
            finally
            {
                if (fileStream != null)
                {
                    fileStream.Dispose();
                }
            }
            Console.WriteLine($"File uploaded to {blobClient.Uri.ToString()}");
        }
    }
}
```

The above code is executed and successfully uploaded to azure blob storage.

I copied the output URL and pasted it in the browser and it displayed the video.

**Output:**

[image]